# Factor analysis - Low and High conditions

Tags: factor-analysis, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

So I'm conducting a factor analysis and also want to test the reliability of the scale. I have 2 conditions (between subjects) : low involvement and high involvement, both composed by the same items. When tested together, the cronbach's alpha is negative, which makes sense because of the negative correlations between the low involvement and high involvement conditions.

Should I just test the scale separately? I mean, for low and high involvement?

Do u guys see what I mean?

Comment: You might consider evaluating whether your factor structure is invariant between these two groups (see Vandenberg & Lance, 2000, for a conceptual review), to ensure that you are actually assessing the same construct in each. If the pattern/values of item loadings, or the values of item intercepts are not equal between groups, you would be making an invalid comparison when comparing scores of those in your two conditions.